# Getting current day as an integer in PHP

Tags: php, date

In PHP I use `getdate()` with `yday` to display current day as a number to certain users. But it increments from 0 and is always one behind the actual day. For example, today (March 6) is 65.

But unless I add 1 to the value, as below, it will display 64:

```
$today = getdate();
$timestamp = $today['yday'];
$timestamp = $timestamp + 1;
```

Is there something that obviates the need for the reassignment above?

Comment: `Numeric representation of the day of the year 0 through 365` so 01/01/17 is 0.

Comment: Read a manual please: `yday - Numeric representation of the day of the year; 0 through 365`

Comment: Yes exactly, in case the other 2 comments were not enough `"yday"  Numeric representation of the day of the year 0 through 365` ___Note from zero___ so `Jan 1 = 0` and 365 only if it is a leap year

Comment: @u_mulder 8-}  1 sec ahead

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions formatting slowed me)))

Comment: Read a manual please? In my post I point out that I'm aware that it starts at ZERO. Less of the attitude.

Comment: @Hego `aware` ok, but why then a false statement if you know? `But it increments from 0 and is always one behind the actual day.` -- wrong The day in year starts from 0 (computer often start from 0 ;-) ), so nothing is `behind`, only if you take this and use it like it is in the real world (but there is no zero day in a year, humans start counting from 1 not 0). But, wahtever, if you dont get it. I thing i dont get you anymore, dont know waht the issue is here.

Comment: Everthing is working like expected and explained in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Much shorter: `echo date('z')+1;`.

And as others have mentioned in the comments, the count for day-number is zero-count, so it starts at 0, which means that you will get a number that you interprete to be 1 smaller than what you want, hence the `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can avoid adding 1 because it's zero indexed (0-365).
So 1st Jan 2016 is 0 (actually - 1st day) and 31st Dec 2016 would be 365 (actually 366th day).

On the plus side you can simplify these three lines to this:

```
date("z")+1;
```